# Selected item in a template, is there any solution for a context aware bindAttr?

Tags: ember.js

The problem is as follows:
In our application we have several buttons, navigation icons etc., which we want to be 'selected' when they have been clicked. We can have multiple elements marked at the same time.

The secondary reason for me wanting to do this is that when I read the new Guides on emberjs.com I get the feeling that templates should be used more than stated before and that templates should have the responsibility of rendering the DOM, while the views should be used to handle sophisticated events (if any) or to create common/shared components to be reused in the application.

Currently the view is handling this:

```
app.NavView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    ...
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        ...
        classNameBindings: ['isSelected:selected']
        isSelected: function () {
            return this.get('controller.selected') === this.get('content');
        }.property('controller.selected')
    })
});
```

But that is all the View basically is doing, I would like to drop the entire View and just use a template for this

I have tried with a template approach, and dropped the entire View concept.

```
<div id="main-menu">
    {{#each content}}
    <div {{bindAttr class="controller.isSelected:selected"}}>
        {{{iconsvg}}}
        {{name}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

But my problem here of course is that bindAttr doesn't know about the context it’s in, and cannot 'send' this to the isSelected property on the controller to evaluate if it is this element that is selected or not.

Is there a good solution to do this without a view, or am I forced to use a view? 
Or am I thinking the design part and responsibility of Templates/views/controllers wrong?

Any response is appreciated!

Comment: Hm, I see in the newest version that there is a ItemController propery in the ArrayController which might solve this. We have just merged from pre2 too router V2, will not start to merge to the new Router V2.x today =), so I will check it in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In the current documentation: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/ there is a mention explaining how to use the {{each}} helper which doesn't override the current context.

In your case, this would be something like:

```
<div id="main-menu">
  {{#each item in controller}}
  <div {{bindAttr class="isSelected:selected"}}>
    {{{item.iconsvg}}}
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Note I have remove the reference to 'controller' in the {{bindAttr}} since I assume it's an ember controller, then it's the current context, so basically isSelected is equivalent to controller.isSelected